# How to update record based on value of next record in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I like to update a column based on a value of the next record:

```
resid   startdate   enddate     weekday hours
-----------------------------------------------
2980    2013-09-23  2014-12-31      1     6
2980    2013-09-23  2014-12-31      2     6
2980    2013-09-23  2014-12-31      3     6
2980    2013-09-23  2014-12-31      4     6
2980    2013-09-23  2014-12-31      5     6
2980    2015-01-01  NULL            1     6,8
2980    2015-01-01  NULL            2     6,8
2980    2015-01-01  NULL            3     6,8
2980    2015-01-01  NULL            4     6,8
2980    2015-01-01  NULL            5     6,8
2980    2015-07-01  NULL            1     6
2980    2015-07-01  NULL            2     6
2980    2015-07-01  NULL            3     6
2980    2015-07-01  NULL            4     6
2980    2015-07-01  NULL            5     6
```

I like to update the NULL value in column `enddate`. It needs to get a value of the next `startdate - 1 day`.

For instance, for all records with `startdate` 2015-01-01, the column `enddate` needs to be updated with 2015-07-01 - 1 day.

Is there someone who has a solution?

Comment: What would you like the enddate value to be on the records where the startdate is 2015-07-01?

Answer (score 0):

```
update TableName set enddate = dateadd(day,1,startdate)
```

Comment: This is not answering the question. the OP wants the end date to be one day before the next start date, not one day after the current start date.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with a subquery:

```
UPDATE t1
SET enddate = (SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(DAY, -1, startdate) 
               FROM YourTable t2 
               WHERE t1.startdate < t2.startdate 
               ORDER BY t2.startdate)
FROM YourTable t1
WHERE t1.enddate is null
```